# Regex get specific words

Tags: c#, regex

I need to get this regex to work but cant figure it out.

```
<li name="random" class="random" id="random" value="random">random</li>
<li name="random" class="random" id="random" value="random">random</li>
<li name="random" class="random" id="random" value="random">Föredrar att inte uppge</li>
```

Random means random data and I want just the last tag data and it can be diffrent amount of tags aswell so every thing between the last "`<li`" and "`Föredrar att inte uppge`"

Comment: is your issue with the regex expression or the code or both?

Comment: just the regex i cant get the data from the li tag i just get the evrything from the first <li> to Föredrar att inte uppge, just the regex expression

Comment: can the adjacent tags have anything between them? if so you can do a search between '>' and '<'

Comment: all the tags has random data except for the last string i put in and that the text in the li tag

Comment: Do I understand this right ... you need the data "name="random" class="random" id="random" value="random"" only from the last li tag in the above example

Comment: I misunderstood what you wanted I think. you should probably give full input/output

Comment: @sundeep yes like you wrote and its allways the last one i can get the data out no problem i just need a way to select the last one

Comment: @user3050767 You could select the last line using ^.*(?![\f\n\r])$ If this line will always have the string "Föredrar att inte uppge" you could also use the regex '<li(.*)>Föredrar att inte uppge'  and then match the first group from it

Comment: Use [htmlagilitypack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).